# Visual Studio F6 stopped working. It no longer builds the project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using VS2008, been using it for quite some time now, and since I [hate using the mouse while developing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000825.html), I'm always using <kbd>F6</kbd> to build the solution, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to build the current project. What's weird though is for some strange reason, it simply stopped working over the last few days. In fact, when I pull down the Build menu, next to "Build MyProject" there's no longer a "<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>" shortcut there on the menu?!? Anyone ever experienced this? Is there a setting I need to change?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can change keyboard bindings in the Tools->Options dialog.  It's under Environment->Keyboard.

You can reset the binding here, and also check what might have stolen it by checking what's currently bound to those keys.

If you recently installed any add-ins, they're known to set (sometimes unwanted) keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me nuts!

Comment: I had the same problem when I installed VM Ware.  SHAME on you VM Ware for overrighting my keyboard short cuts with you VS plugin.

Comment: Grrr!  Luckily I'm still on my 30-day free trial of VMWare Workstation.  Hijacking the VS keyboard shortcuts is a HUGE minus.  Looks like another point for sticking with the free VirtualBox (its faster and less bloated than VMWare anyway and doesn't require a reboot to install the thing).

Comment: I see zounds of options for building here. Which one is it and how do I assign F6 to it? You did good up until you left the answer hanging at ->Keyboard saying we can reset the binding here :)

Comment: I used it, set it to shift f6 but still does not work

Comment: setting it to Visual C# 2005 did it for me. for some reason in the newest version that is no longer the default.

Answer (score 32):

Your Keyboard Mapping Scheme has changed.
Go to Tools -> Options. In Environments->Keyboard in the dropdown for "Apply the following additional mapping scheme" select **"Visual C# 2005"**

Comment: And don't click the 'reset' button ... like I did ... thinking that would (re)set the keyboard to the selected value. Select 'Visual C# 2005' and then click OK button.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried :  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

All the keyboard shortcuts have been shown there.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add the proverbial "Is it plugged into the wall" question:

Do you have a fancy keyboard that replaces function keys with other things toggled incorrectly?

Comment: I can confirm it was VM Ware workstation which adds an add-in to VS

Answer (score 2):

VMWare stole my <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.  Maybe that's your prob?

I fixed this by going to going to tool-options-environment-keyboard just like the other suggestions but I clicked "Reset" instead to restore the proper short cuts.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper was annoying about this.
I had to set BuildSolution to f6
then remove F6 from Resharper_Move

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this bites anyone else: [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/uk/products/desktop/) for OS X grabs <kbd>F6</kbd> and uses it for "Show and hide Parallels Desktop". It can be disabled in Preferences -> OS X System Shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an answer but it is good to have this here for future reference:

On the Solution properties page, Configuration Properties -> Configuration, the list of projects will be  displayed and the last column "Build" will have checkboxes, one for each project. 
If they are all unchecked, you will press F6 but nothing will happen. Check the projects you want to build, on that case and you are now good to hit F6.